# How to prevent someone from entering my website unless they are using google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have searched all over for a way to prevent someone from entering my sight unless they are using chrome.

I am really not interested in opinions about whether or not this is a good idea, that can be saved for another subjective discussion.

I am seeking an answer on how can I make sure that my website limits browser support to chrome users only. It has to restrict entry, and offer a link to install chrome. If the visitor is already using chrome, it should be able to recognize that an allow the user to enter
.

Can anyone help me with this please.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Comment: How secure does the restriction need to be? It will be very easy to circumvent if you use JavaScript to implement it

Comment: "prevent someone from entering my sight unless they are using chrome." i wish it were possible. (invisible IE users)

Comment: Use server-side user-agent testing, redirect to your `denied access please d/l chrome` page.

Comment: Do you work for Google ?

Comment: @ Pekka - It does not need to be secure, it just needs to make that point.

Comment: @cirusdei I think it is possible.

Comment: There is no secure way to prevent access to a single browser (nearly every browser lets you alter the user agent via plugins). But the idea is http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/126/314/3cd8a33a.png

Comment: @ok thank you Kevin, but I might need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
if(!is_chrome) {
    document.write("DOWNLOAD CHROME HERE!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (!window.chrome) window.location.href = 'http://site.com/chrome_dl.html';
</script>
```

Comment: so it would look like this right?

<head>
<script>
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
</script>
</head>

Comment: Yes, stick it in a `<script type="text/javascript">` tag in the head, and create a nice page that you redirect to that tells the user to download chrome etc.

Answer (score -2):

In Javascript use:

```
If (navigator.appName != "netscape"){
  window.location.href = "Download_Chrome.html";
}
```

And make sure you have a page named Download_Chrome.html in the same directory.
Note: if you wondering why it is checking if the appname = netscape, is because chrome identifies itself as that.